# How to show full price in super attribute drop-down instead of only the increased price in Magento?

Tags: magento2, price, superattribute

I've created a configurable product with a super attribute.
It works great and i can select the different products from the dropdown menu.

Now my question is the following: Is it possible to also include the full price in the dropdown menu instead of only the increased price per product?

I have added an image as an example

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?